# Meaning of ${xxx:yyy} on Spring Boot application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I see following in Spring Boot `application.properties` file. What is it doing here:

```
spring.datasource.password = ${DB_PASSWD:password}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means try resolving `DB_PASSWD` property. If found, use it's value. If not, use the default provided value `password`. In short:

```
${property:defaultValue}
```

The property value is looked up from property sources registered in Spring context, see [`Environment.getProperty()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) and [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).

Comment: perfect. Thank you.